# Error 42803. la columna XXXX debe aparecer en la cláusula GROUP BY o ser usada en una función de agregación

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, sum

Al intentar hacer un `over (order by Id asc rows between unbounded preceding and current row)` **sobre un** **sumatorio**, con la intencion de ir obteniendo un acumulado de las respectivas sumas, se devuelven resultados erroneos por acumulado
Esta es la query que he alcanzado a conseguir:

```
SELECT  c.id AS Id, c.centro AS Description,  g.id as GroupId, cuen.id as BillId, r.mes_actualizado as UpdatedMonth, cri.agno_mes as YearMonth, gc.signo as Sign, 
    cuen.descripcion->>:language as Bill, false as Comparable, true as Divisor, 
    SUM(cri.importe_cal * gc.signo) over (order by c.Id asc rows between unbounded preceding and current row) AS Amount , 
    g.descripcion->> :language as Group, g.es_total as IsTotal,
    cri.importe, cri.importe_cal  
    FROM public.tabla1 m 
    INNER JOIN public.tabla2 mg ON(mg.ef_modelo_id = m.id) 
    INNER JOIN public.tabla3 g ON(g.id = mg.ef_grupo_id) 
    INNER JOIN public.tabla4 gc ON(gc.ef_grupo_id = g.id) 
    INNER JOIN public.tabla5 cuen ON(cuen.id = gc.ef_cuenta_id) 
    INNER JOIN public.tabla6 cri ON(cri.ef_cuenta_id = cuen.id) 
    INNER JOIN public.tabla7 r ON(r.id = cri.ef_real_id) 
    INNER JOIN public.tabla8 c ON(c.id = r.centro_id )  
    INNER JOIN public.tabla9 mr ON(m.id = mr.ef_modelo_id) 
    INNER JOIN public.tabla10  u ON(mr.rol_id = u.tpl_rol_id) 
    INNER JOIN public.tabla11 cu ON(cu."userId" = u."pId") AND(cu.centro_id = r.centro_id) 
    WHERE u."pId" = :userId AND g.id = :Group AND m.id = :TypeFinancialStatement AND ( cri.agno_mes BETWEEN :dateFrom AND :dateTo ) 
    GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,14,15
```

No sé como solucionarlo.

Comment: Excepto aquellas que están en funciones de agregación como `sum` y `count` has probado pasar todas las columnas de tu `select` al group by?

Comment: Hola @BetaM, gracias por contestar. Me devuelve el mismo error: la columna «cri.importe_cal» debe aparecer en la cláusula GROUP BY o ser usada en una función de agregación

Comment: Quita el `over by`  no tiene sentido en este caso.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho ayuda a generar el acumulado del sumatorio paso por paso. He visto los resultados y es necesario. Gracias por contestar.

Comment: O, si estas acumulando y no haciendo una suma por grupo, entonces, el problema lo tienes en `GROUP BY` , quita `gc.signo` del mismo.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho lo hice, y me dice que tiene que estar en el GROUP BY o ser usada en una funcion de agregacion

Comment: ¿lo quitaste de `SELECT` y del `GROUP BY`? que `gc.signo` quede solo dentro del `SUM`

Comment: Solo del group by, del select lo necesito. @PatricioMoracho

Comment: Entonces por este camino no tenemos solución posible. Por que no empezamos por el principio?, olvidate del problema actual, define en tu pregunta que es lo que buscas con con la consulta, haz un ejemplo básico de los datos y muéstranos la salida que esperas. Con eso tal vez podamos encontrar la forma de resolverlo.

Comment: Evita el uso de números para identificar columns. Es una práctica que atrae errores.

Comment: @TheImpaler tienes razon. Lo tendre en cuenta